# how to select table from a different server having backslash in the name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to query a table that exists in a different server/ database etc.

select top 1 * from 'serverdd\foobar'.mydatabase.mytable

My problem is that I have a backslash in the server name..

So how do I write the query for this kind of server name. I did enclose it with single quote but it did not work. I get "an incorrect" syntax error.

Comment: `[serverdd\foobar].mydatabase.mytable`

Comment: I get an error Invalid object name

Comment: Yeah, theres no schema. dbo? `[serverdd\foobar].mydatabase.dbo.mytable`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.. Please elaborate

Comment: now I get the error .. could not find the server in sys.servers

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [ServerName\InstanceName].[Database].[Schema].[Table]` use square brackets `[]` around all the object names. Also make sure that server is added as Linked server.

Comment: `sp_addlinkedserver`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: I need to make a query across servers... from one server to another server ..

Comment: Could not find server in sys.servers.. your solutions are not working because that server name is a different server

Comment: Our solutions are addressing the question of how to address an identifier with a backslash in it (as asked). Maybe your problem is actually with setting up the linked server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add the "linked server". Here is a link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190479.aspx

Probably it will look something like this (though I usually use the GUI):

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server=N'serverdd_foobar', 
   @srvproduct=N'',
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI', 
   @datasrc=N'serverdd\foobar';
```

When you link a server you give it a friendly name. In the above example I named it without the backslash. You can access the server using this name:

```
SELECT * FROM serverdd_foobar.database.schema.table
```

If any of these elements contain invalid characters (like a backslash) you will want to enclose that element in square brackets. Double quotes usually works too, but that can be turned off; single quotes will never work.